# Sending characters using pipes in C

Tags: c, process, char, pipe, parent-child

I am trying to send **string** from parent process to child process using pipes in **C** programming language, it works almost correctly, but I receive incomplete string without first character. What is I wrong in my code? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    int pid, p[2];
    int status = -100;
    char input[100];
    char inputBuffer[100];

    if(pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if((pid = fork())<0)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(pid==0)
        {


            close(p[1]);
            while(1)
            {
                if(!read(p[0],&inputBuffer,1))
                {
                    close(p[0]);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    read(p[0],&inputBuffer,100);
                }
            }
            printf("received: %s\n",inputBuffer);
            exit(0);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter String\n");
            scanf("%s", &input);
            printf("String Entered: %s\n",input);
            close(p[0]);
            write(p[1], input, strlen(input)+1);
            close(p[1]);
            wait(&status);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you first read 1 byte to see if it isn't a nul terminator but then that information is gone because you overwrite it in the latter call! So you need to increment the pointer on the latter call.

```
if(!read(p[0],&inputBuffer,1))
{
  close(p[0]);
  break;
}
else
{
  char *pointer = &inputBuffer;
  read(p[0],pointer+1,99);
}
```